# Find an element in an irregular list in python

Tags: list, python-3.x, recursion

I have the following class

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, elements):
        self.elements = elements
```

I need to write a function that takes two instances of it, and finds if instance 1 is in the elements of instance 2. This is an irregular list, because those elements contain more instances of A to an arbitrary depth.

I want something along those lines:

```
def is_element_in(instanceA1, instanceA2):

    found = False

    for inherit in instanceA2.instanceof.inherits:
        if instanceA1 == inherit:
            found = True
        else:
            n_inherit(instanceA1, inherit)

    return found
```

What's the best way to write this? I read some answers about flattening the list. I don't know if it's the best idea here, because I have to access fields to get my list of elements. Any python libraries that can be used here?

Comment: Let me see if a got it. You have some list like `[[1, 2], [3], [[4], 5]]` and want to find the number `4`?

Comment: Yea, I want it so if 4 is there, I return true

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possible solution is

```
def is_element_in(items, element):
    for item in items:
        if item == element:
            return True

        if isinstance(item, list) and is_element_in(item, element):
            return True

    return False

items = [[1, 2], [3], [[4], 5]]

print(is_element_in(items, 4))
print(is_element_in(items, 0))
```

Prints

```
True
False
```

Comment: The OP said, that the nesting depth is arbitrary. We probably should try an iterative approach instead of recursive.

Comment: Doing it recursively is very intuitive, so I don't think another aproach is desired. You probably are saying that for performance reasons, which I agree with you but it is not a concern for now. Anyway we are re-inventing the wheel (it is certainly already implemented in some well-known lib and it should be used instead).